# regex help - finding everything until the previous space character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to figure out regular expressions and am having trouble parsing the following.

I have several hundred lines that look like so:

```
source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/myfiles/Clustering/Code/Connectedness/Code; R CMD BATCH "--vanilla --args BRAF P15056 BRAF_P15056_MutationOutput.txt 3NY5.pdb A"  MutationAnalysisRunMeAlignment.R ~/myfiles/Clustering/ROutput/RunOutputAlignment/BRAF_P15056_3NY5_A_RunResults.txt
```

I want to find the part of the string that ends with "MutationOutput.txt" and match it up to  the previous space. I then want to replace it with nothing. Thus the above line would become:

```
source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/myfiles/Clustering/Code/Connectedness/Code; R CMD BATCH "--vanilla --args BRAF P15056 3NY5.pdb A"  MutationAnalysisRunMeAlignment.R ~/myfiles/Clustering/ROutput/RunOutputAlignment/BRAF_P15056_3NY5_A_RunResults.txt
```

I know it needs to be something like this,

```
[A-Z_0-9]MutationOutput.txt
```

but how that only captures the final part of the line: "_MutationOutput.txt". How do I make it count everything until the previous space character?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything between the //:
`/ [^ ]*MutationOutput\.txt/`

What this means is "space, then a bunch of stuff that isn't spaces, then MutationOutput.txt". (I did it this way because I'm not sure how Notepad++ works with greedy vs. nongreedy.)

By the way, you could make your first try work better too. A character class (characters between `[]`) matches only one character, but you can make it match zero or more with `*`. Actually, you can make anything match zero or more of that thing with `*`.

Comment: as a general rule, if matching up to a certain character, then it is better to to use a `[^<matchingchar>]` because it means less backtracking for the regex engine. Its a standard and decent optimization (like `/<[^>]+>/` for angle-brackets).